# How to convert day-of-year to month, day-of-month with tidyverse

Tags: r, date, tidyverse, lubridate

There are a number of queries on similar date-conversion problems using `as.Date()` and `tidyverse / lubridate` functions, but I am getting the wrong answers for my problem, and can't figure out why.

My data is `vcdExtra::Draft1970` containing `Day = 1:366`  of the year
and the `Rank` of selection in the US Draft Lottery. My reprex is below:

```r
library(tidyverse)
data(Draft1970, package = "vcdExtra")
glimpse(Draft1970)
#> Rows: 366
#> Columns: 3
#> $ Day   <int> 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 1…
#> $ Rank  <int> 305, 159, 251, 215, 101, 224, 306, 199, 194, 325, 329, 221, 318,…
#> $ Month <ord> Jan, Jan, Jan, Jan, Jan, Jan, Jan, Jan, Jan, Jan, Jan, Jan, Jan,…

Draft1970 |> 
  arrange(Rank) |> 
  relocate(Rank) |>
  mutate(mday = lubridate::mday(as.Date(Day, origin="1970-01-01"))) |> 
  mutate(Date = paste(Month, mday, sep=" ")) |> head(6)
#>   Rank Day Month mday   Date
#> 1    1 258   Sep   16 Sep 16
#> 2    2 115   Apr   26 Apr 26
#> 3    3 365   Dec    1  Dec 1
#> 4    4  45   Feb   15 Feb 15
#> 5    5 292   Oct   20 Oct 20
#> 6    6 250   Sep    8  Sep 8
```

<sup>Created on 2023-07-01 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

The problem is that the converted `Date` is **wrong** by one or two days.
The first 4 dates should be:

```
  Rank Day   Date
1    1 258 Sep 14
2    2 115 Apr 24
3    3 365  Dec 30
4    4  45 Feb 14
```

Comment: You probably need `origin = "1969-12-31"` which is the date corresponding to zero. Also, 1970 was not a leap year, so had 365 days, not 366. So it doesn't look like the `Draft1970` data (at least the way you are using it) is actually consistent with being from that year.

Comment: From the documentation: "The days of the year (including February 29) were represented by the numbers 1 through 366 written on slips of paper."  It looks like you need to correct for non-leap years.

Comment: Re: leap year -- the draft lottery had to account for all 366 possible BIRTHDAYs, even if Feb 29 did not occur in 1970

Comment: @user101089 Yes, but you're asking lubridate to do its calculations for 1970, which is not a leap year.

Answer (score 0):

There were, indeed two errors in my simple approach:

- day 0 should have been `xxxx-12-311
- I should have chosen an origin where the **next** year was a leap year with 366 days.

Making these corrections, i.e., with 1971-12-31 as `origin` gives the right answers:

```r
library(tidyverse)
data(Draft1970, package = "vcdExtra")
Draft1970 |> 
  arrange(Rank) |> 
  relocate(Rank) |>
  mutate(mday = lubridate::mday(as.Date(Day, origin="1971-12-31"))) |> 
  mutate(Date = paste(Month, mday, sep=" ")) |> head(8)
#>   Rank Day Month mday   Date
#> 1    1 258   Sep   14 Sep 14
#> 2    2 115   Apr   24 Apr 24
#> 3    3 365   Dec   30 Dec 30
#> 4    4  45   Feb   14 Feb 14
#> 5    5 292   Oct   18 Oct 18
#> 6    6 250   Sep    6  Sep 6
#> 7    7 300   Oct   26 Oct 26
#> 8    8 251   Sep    7  Sep 7
```

<sup>Created on 2023-07-01 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>